# What are the areas, relating to database or server, that should be viewed while making map based webapplication?

Tags: geoserver, wms, spatial-database, sql-server

This question is relating to GIS web application that are based on relational database. I have database that is not indexed with spatial column and I use geoserver to display these data as layers. But for a single layer that is displayed zooming in and out takes time(Intranet or localhost). Are there anything that can be done so that the application can respond faster? 
I have used:

```
1.Geoserver
2.SQl-SERVER 2008
3.Openlayers and geoExt
4.No of rows nearly 3000 only for each layers or less (200)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/) to cache the rendered tiles so that displaying tiles at a certain zoom level will be much faster. GeoWebCache is actually integrated into GeoServer, so you can see [the GeoServer documentation for how to enable it](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html).

You'll also want to make sure that your layers in OpenLayers are configured correctly so that GeoWebCache will be able to serve them up. Once you've enabled GeoWebCache, go to the GWC demos page in your GeoServer installation and click on one of the OpenLayers demos. View the source and you will see example code of how to configure OpenLayers correctly with the bounds and GWC-supported projections.

That should drastically improve performance once a tile has been rendered at least once. However, for the first render, things are not going to get any faster unless you have a spatially indexed data store.

Comment: Actually, one other thing — make sure you have native JAI extensions installed, as these really improve 2D rendering performance. You can check this on the GeoServer status page. If they're not installed, follow these instructions: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html#installing-native-jai-on-windows

Comment: nice tips must be userful for everyone but more info on spatial indexing would be useful :) +1

Comment: The only spatially indexed data store that I have familiarity with is PostGIS. For SQL Server though, you could try creating spatial indexes on your geometry columns following the directions here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964705.aspx